# Getting error while running npx expo:android

Tags: react-native, expo

- Where:

Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/green-red/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build.gradle' line: 372

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-modules-core'.

> 

Cannot invoke method replace() on null object

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

when running npx expo run:android